# Adding bower component to gulpfile

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, gulp, bower, bower-install

I don't know why, but I have a problem with a little Yeoman project with Bower and Gulp.

Little question:

I installed a component with this command.

```
bower install angular-bootstrap-show-errors -S
```

That's works great.

But if I look in the gulpfile.js of my project it looks like.

```
vendor: {
  js: [
    './bower_components/angular/angular.js',
    './bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
    './bower_components/mobile-angular-ui/dist/js/mobile-angular-ui.js'
  ],

  fonts: [
    './bower_components/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.*'
  ]
},
```

**But the installed component is missing.**

I've tried to search with google but I can't find any solution.

If I try to add `config.vendor.js.push('.bower_components/angular-bootstrap-show-errors/src/showErrors.js');` to `config.js` it wouldn't work, too. (After `bower install` and `gulp build`)

**How I can add a installed bower component to gulp?**

Thanks in advance for any idea!

Answer (score 0):

Bower's only responsibility is to update the `bower.json` file. You can just add it to your gulpfile

```
vendor: {
  js: [
    './bower_components/angular/angular.js',
    './bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
    './bower_components/mobile-angular-ui/dist/js/mobile-angular-ui.js',
    './bower_components/angular-bootstrap-show-errors/src/showErrors.js'
  ],

  fonts: [
    './bower_components/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.*'
  ]
},
```

---

*Edit:*

For `angular-mobile-ui`, instead of altering the gulpfile, add

**config.js:**

```
config.vendor.js.push('.bower_components/angular-bootstrap-show-errors/src/showErrors.js');
```

and `'ui.bootstrap.showErrors'` to your app's dependencies:

**/src/js/app.js:**

```
angular.module('MyApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'mobile-angular-ui',
  'ui.bootstrap.showErrors',
  'MyApp.controllers.Main'
])
```

This works because in the gulpfile the settings in `config.js` are loaded by:

```
if (require('fs').existsSync('./config.js')) {
  var configFn = require('./config');
  configFn(config);
}
```

Comment: But there is a comment at the top of the file: `// Please use config.js to override these selectively:`

Comment: What generator are you using?

Comment: I added the config.vendor.js.push to the config.js. But how i regenerate the gulpfile.js?

Comment: The gulpfile isn't regenerated, the config file adds, overrides or alters settings of the gulpfile.